# How to use and create and handle Model class in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios6, singleton

i want to increment and decrement a variable trough out the application as i am using that in many views of the application. I am working on a game for iOS. I want to store the score in a variable and when the user start playing game there are two or three points where the users can loose the score like -1 before start playing the game even. Suppose i am giving the user three options for something if he choose first then he move to the next step if he will return back and want to choose second option he will have to bear -1 from his score and again if he go for third same process will be followed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only have to make singleton class to solve this

follow the answer [What should my Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-should-my-objective-c-singleton-look-like)   it have the idea of singleton